# Get iOS contact image with ABPersonCopyImageData

Tags: ios, swift, abaddressbook

I'm trying to read the contact image of my iOS addressbook but I'm having some troubles with it.

I have a method that read the information of contacts of ABAddressBookRef and put it on a struct.

```
func readContacts(addressBook: ABAddressBookRef){
        let allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef).takeRetainedValue() as NSArray
        var numeros : [Numeros] = []

        //lendo todos os contatos
        for person: ABRecordRef in allPeople{

            let firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as! String
            let lastName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as! String

            let phones : ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeUnretainedValue() as ABMultiValueRef

            let data = ABPersonCopyImageData(person).takeRetainedValue() as NSData
            let imagemContato = UIImage(data: data)

            for(var numberIndex : CFIndex = 0; numberIndex < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); numberIndex++) {
                let phoneUnmaganed = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, numberIndex)

                let phoneNumber : NSString = phoneUnmaganed.takeUnretainedValue() as! NSString

                let locLabel : CFStringRef = (ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, numberIndex) != nil) ? ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, numberIndex).takeUnretainedValue() as CFStringRef : ""

                let cfStr:CFTypeRef = locLabel
                let nsTypeString = cfStr as! NSString
                let swiftString:String = nsTypeString as String

                //let customLabel = String (stringInterpolationSegment: ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(locLabel))

                let numero: Numeros = Numeros(tipoNumero: swiftString, numero: phoneNumber as String)

                numeros.append(numero)

            }

            let registroContato: Contato = Contato(primeiroNome: firstName, ultimoNome: lastName, contatoRecord: person, numeros: numeros, imagemContato: imagemContato!)

            contatos.append(registroContato)

        }
    }
```

but when I debug it, it stops on:

```
let data = ABPersonCopyImageData(person).takeRetainedValue() as NSData
```

and doesn't show any error message.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using the simulator default contacts to test it, they did not have images but have the placeholder with his/her first letter of the name.

EDITED:

i've change the code to

```
let imagemContato: UIImage?
            if let data = ABPersonCopyImageData(person)?.takeRetainedValue() as? NSData     {
                print("\(firstName) with image")
                imagemContato = UIImage(data: data)
            }
            else {
                print("\(firstName) without image")
                imagemContato = UIImage(named: "UooQo.jpg")
            }
```

and on the console all contacts have no image:

console output:
**Kate without image
Daniel without image
John without image
Anna without image
Hank without image
David without image**

it shows no image for contact but i add one to John.
[image: contact image]

Comment: I'll get the easy explanation out of the way, it's not a breakpoint is it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem that I faced in my project earlier.
Try this,

//To Get image

```
   let img = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail).takeRetainedValue()
```

//To set image in your ImageView

```
YourImageView.image=UIImage(data: img as! NSData)
```

Comment: it stops the same as my code :(  I've edited my question with more information

Comment: Sorry friend you have to check whether image  s available for a contact by following code 'if ABPersonHasImageData(person) {let img = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail).takeRetainedValue()}'

Comment: thank you! it works, see above what i did and if it the best way.

Comment: @Marchiore, Pls flag above comment its help to others, Happy coding... :)

Answer (score 4):

The `AddressBook` framework is one of the frameworks that is really nasty to use with Swift.  First I'll point out that there is a new [Contacts](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html) framework in iOS 9, which I would suggest you use if you have the option of not supporting 8 and earlier (`AddressBook` is deprecated as of iOS 9).

Having said that, the function `ABPersonCopyImageData(ABRecord!)` returns a value that has the type `Unmanaged<CFData>!`, which means that it is possible that it will be a `nil` value (it really should be `Unmanaged<CFData>?`, but I think Apple didn't bother fixing up AddressBook types because they were working on the `Contacts` framework instead.  Given that it can and will return `nil`, you'll need to treat it like it could be `nil` even though it is an implicitly unwrapped type.

Change:

```
let data = ABPersonCopyImageData(person).takeRetainedValue() as NSData
let imagemContato = UIImage(data: data)
```

to:

```
let imagemContato: UIImage?
if let data = ABPersonCopyImageData(person)?.takeRetainedValue() as? NSData     {
    imagemContato = UIImage(data: data)
}
else {
    imagemContato = nil
}
```

**Note**: Later on in your code you force unwrap `imagemContato` when you create your `Contato` instance.  You will have to handle the case where it is a `nil` value or your program will potentially crash when you do this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Charles A, but it does not find the photos of the contacts, even though I set them in the simulator. I've edited my question with more information

Comment: You need change 'imageContato' type from 'let' to 'var'. You can't change the value inside the if statement otherwise.

Comment: @DineshRaja You cannot change the value, but the statements in the if/else blocks assign an initial value.  Constants allow initialization anytime prior to the first use of them in Swift (as of Swift 1.2).  Try it out.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. I'm working on Swift 2.1. :) Still, you have to update the code. So it will work in updated swift versions.

Comment: @DineshRaja It works in 2.1 also, it was added in 1.2.  Have you tried to compile this code?  It won't work in Swift 1.0, but I doubt many people are still using that.

Comment: If you copy and paste the code above it compiles.  Are you sure you didn't have multiple assignments?  For example, having `let imagemContato: UIImage? = nil` as the first line instead of `let imagemContato: UIImage?` will cause what you describe.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. it was another variable brought the confusion. Thank your for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it using

```
        let imagemContato: UIImage?
        let imgData: CFData?

        if ABPersonHasImageData(person) {
            imgData = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail).takeRetainedValue()
            imagemContato = UIImage(data: imgData!)
        }else{
            //placeholder
            imagemContato = UIImage(named: "UooQo.jpg")
        }
```

is this the correct way?