# iOS AddressBook - get contact image crash

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

There is some problem with AddressBook which I can't reproduce, code works on my iPhone and iPad, this happens on client phone and result in app crash. As far as I can see from Crashlytics problem should be in following line:

```
let data = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(contact, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail).takeRetainedValue()
```

Here is complete code for reading address book:

```
    var err : Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
    let addressBookRef : ABAddressBook? = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &err).takeRetainedValue()
    if addressBookRef == nil {
        print(err)
        return
    }

    let contacts = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef).takeRetainedValue() as NSArray as [ABRecord]
    for contact in contacts {
        let firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(contact, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as? String
        let lastName = ABRecordCopyValue(contact, kABPersonLastNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as? String

        var image: UIImage?
        if ABPersonHasImageData(contact) {

            let data = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(contact, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail).takeRetainedValue()
            if let img = UIImage(data: data) {
                image = img
            }

        }


        …
}
```

Do you have any suggestions what could happen on clients phone so I can reproduce this error? Is it possible that some contact is corrupt? How should I handle this?

I've seen this post [Get iOS contact image with ABPersonCopyImageData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924341/get-ios-contact-image-with-abpersoncopyimagedata/32924944#32924944) that ABPersonCopyImageData could return nil, I tried to handle that but app is still crashing.

Comment: Could you put in the code that "tried to handle that" please? The linked post looks like it's treating the optional data properly.

Comment: you should try to check this code with nil image contact

Comment: Could you please add stack trace and/or error message to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check all for nil. if ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat returns nil, you call takeRetainedValue on nil. and then use it nil to create image too

```
guard let CFData = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(contact, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail) else {
    print("no cfdata")
    return
}

if let data = CFData.takeRetainedValue {
     if let img = UIImage(data: data) {
         image = img
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should test the data itself and not the UIImage and also initialize an UIImageView instead of a UIImage.

```
if let data = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(contact, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail).takeRetainedValue()
    image = UIImage(data: data)
}
```